# cakephp Loading RequestHandler on the fly not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, php-5.3

I am trying to use the Request handler component but am getting the following error:-

> Fatal error: Call to a member function is() on a non-object.

The following is my code when I access my `getFirstMethod` it will call the `getSecondMethod` from there again it will call the `getThirdMethod` in that method I need to load the `RequestHandlerComponent`.

FirstController.php:

```
App::uses(SecondController, Controller/Profiles);
public $components = array(Session,RequestHandler);
function getFirstMethod(){ 
    SecondController::getSecondMethod($inputs())
}
```

SecondController.php

```
App::uses(ThirdController, Controller/Common);
function getSecondMethod(){
    ThirdController::getPhotos($inputs())
}
```

ThirdController.php:

```
public $components = array(Session,RequestHandler);
function getThirdMethod()
{
$request = new RequestHandlerComponent(new ComponentCollection(),array())
if($request->isAjax()){ } // **ERROR**
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){} //
```

Also in some cases we need to access `getThirdMethod` directly so only isAjax need to check.

I am using CakePHP 2.0.

Comment: Why are you calling methods between controllers? You shouldn't do this! If you need to share functionality between controllers use a Component.

Comment: Also, what is `$inputs()` as you don't seem to set it anywhere!

Comment: [~drmonkeyninja] $inputs is some array of data. I accept your point like calling methods between controllers.. Already the application is developed  by some one and  currently I am trying to fixing this (maintenance)

Comment: It's hard to help you with the current example code, it would be more helpful to see the actual methods you are using. From what I can see your issue is that you are trying to call methods between controllers and unless you fix that problem you are not going to get very far solving your issue.